# How to integrate the volume of a parametric equation

Tags: integration, volume

Given the curve described by

$x(t)=a(t-sin(t))$ and $y(t)=a(1-cos(t))$ for $t$ in the interval $[0,2\pi]$

How do I find the volume of a Solid $S$ result of making the area between the curve and $y=0$ rotate around the x axis

So far I have just gotten that the curve is similar to the positive side of an elipse but don't know exactly how to describe the curve in  cartesian coordinates or if there is a way to integrate the given curve as it is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done with a simple change of variables.

$$dx=a(1-\cos t)\,dt$$

$$V=\int_{x(0)}^{x(2\pi)}\pi y^2\,dx=\int_0^{2\pi}\pi(a(1-\cos t))^2a(1-\cos t)\,dt=\pi a^3\int_0^{2\pi}(1-\cos t)^3\,dt$$

Do you think you can take it from here?

Comment: Yes I can take it from here but I did not quite understand what you do, could you explain please?

Comment: I took the ordinary equation for the volume of a curve revolved around the $x$-axis. That is $$V=\int_a^b \pi y^2 dx$$ It's sometimes called the disk method, or the ring method. I simply made the substitution to get an integral in terms of $dt$. The equation of $dx$ in terms of $dt$ can be found by just taking the derivative of $x(t)$

Comment: Should not it be $2\pi$ instead of just $\pi$ in the formula?

Comment: @G.nino You can take a look at the [disk method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disc_integration) yourself. The integrand should definitely be $\pi y^2\, dx$. Maybe you are thinking of the [shell method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shell_integration)?